# How to interact with DOM on a UWP WebView?

Tags: uwp

I have a UWP XAML Page and a WebView

```
<WebView Name="webview1" Margin="10"
             Source="http://www.apelosurgentes.com.br/en-us/" 
             LoadCompleted="WebView_LoadCompleted" />
```

How to read and manipulate the DOM of the document that was loaded on this WebView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to interact with DOM on a UWP WebView?

You can use [`InvokeScriptAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_InvokeScriptAsync_System_String_System_String___) with the JavaScript eval function to use the HTML event handlers, and to use window.external.notify from the HTML event handler to notify the application using [`WebView.ScriptNotify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_ScriptNotify).

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string functionString = String.Format("document.getElementById('nameDiv').innerText = 'Hello, {0}';", nameTextBox.Text);
    await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
}
```

Scripts in the web view content can use window.external.notify with a string parameter to send information back to your app. To receive these messages, handle the ScriptNotify event.

```
public MyPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MyWebView.ScriptNotify += MyWebView_ScriptNotify;

    // Here we have to set the AllowedScriptNotifyUri property because we are 
    // navigating to some site where we don't own the content and we want to 
    // allow window.external.notify() to pass data back to the app.
    List<Uri> allowedUris = new List<Uri>();
    allowedUris.Add(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"));
    MyWebView.AllowedScriptNotifyUris = allowedUris;
}

void MyWebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    // Respond to the script notification.
}
```

For more, Please refer to UWP [`WebView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/web-view).