# How to access and manipulate the DOM and JavaScript of WebView?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a WebView that I navigate to a URL, and I want to read the contents, Interact with the JavaScript, etc.

I tried

XAML:

```
<WebView Name="wv1" LoadCompleted="wv1_LoadCompleted" />
```

C# code:

```
private void wv1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var uri = e.Uri;

    var c = e.Content;
}
```

The problem is that the `e.Uri` is returned, but the `e.Content` is null.

How to access the DOM?
How can I do that?

Comment: This answer tells about the JavaScript + WebView + UWP, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46961670/how-to-interact-with-dom-on-a-uwp-webview

Comment: Hi Tony does the below answer work in your side?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that the e.Uri is returned, but the e.Content is null.

The [`Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationeventargs.content#Windows_UI_Xaml_Navigation_NavigationEventArgs_Content) property of [`NavigationEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationeventargs) is used to get the root node of the target page's content. The page is xaml page but not web page. You could verify it with [`Frame.Navigated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigated) event. When page navigated you could get value of `Content`.

```
private void RootFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Content.ToString()); 
}
```

If you want to get the web page content. you could refer this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46969630/7254781). With some updates:

> To enable an external web page to fire the ScriptNotify event when calling window.external.notify, you must include the page's Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) in the **ApplicationContentUriRules** section of the app manifest.

The follow eval method used to get body html.

```
string functionString = @"window.external.notify(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML)";
await Test.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
```

And you could get the return value form `ScriptNotify` event handler.

```
private void Test_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    var body = e.Value;
}
```